# Can you loop if statements in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

First off, let me apologize if this is a stupid simple solution. I am currently in college and I am working on a project to create an AD enviroment with users, OUs, GPOs etc. I am hoping there's a way to loop the if statement asking if you want to create an Organizational Unit so instead of repeating the same lines, it would look cleaner and be more usable in a real world scenario.

Currently, I am using: But, if you wanted to create more than the two prompts, you couldn't.

```
#Create OUs
$Create_OU1= Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to create any Organizational Units? Y/N"
if ($Create_OU1 -eq "Y" -or $Create_OU1 -eq "Yes") {
   
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit
   
}   

$Create_OU2= Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to create any additional Organizational Units? Y/N"
if ($Create_OU2 -eq "Y" -or $Create_OU2 -eq "Yes") {
   
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit
    }
Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to create any additional Organizational Units? Y/N"
```

Comment: a [`do` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.3) is an excellent fit for your need.

Comment: So would it just be 

do {
$Create_OU= Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to create any Organizational Units? Y/N"
if ($Create_OU -eq "Y" -or $Create_OU -eq "Yes") {

} Until ($Create_OU -eq "N" -or $Create_OU -eq "No")

Comment: What arguments are you using for `New-ADOrganizationalUnit` or are you just calling the cmdlet and feeding arguments manually ?

Comment: I tried passing the -name and -path but it still prompted for a name. So for now I am just manually entering

Comment: I'm a little confuse on the request here. Will the new questions to rather the OU needs to be created store into array or create OU as you stated yes then reprompt?

Comment: Apologies for not replying, didn't see your comment. I was trying to prompt and ask if you want to create any. If yes, enter the values, and repeat the prompt until no is selected

Comment: Why do you need the loop? Entering just `New-ADOrganizationalUnit` using the console history provides the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with a [`do` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.3) and [`PromptForChoice` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) the code would look like this:

```
$prompt = {
    param($message)

    $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($null, $message, ('&Yes', '&No'), 0)
}

$message1 = 'Do you want to create any Organizational Units?'
$message2 = 'Do you want to create any additional Organizational Units?'

if((& $prompt $message1) -eq 0) {
    do {
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit
    }
    while((& $prompt $message2) -eq 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a huge help, but it's passing the OU cmdlet before the prompt for choice.

Comment: Thank you! It's still passing the cmdlet after the do loop ends, but that's a minor issue.